# can xml node contain python list as text?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml.etree

I am trying to edit a xml file. I need to input data to a new node that i create. THe data to be inputted to the new node is in the form of python list. Can I in any way using lxml or any other library achieve this.

```
post = etree.Element("post")
post.text =  [1,2,3]
```

Is this thing possible?

Comment: I think you'd better like to use `json` to serialize your data. But you can always serialize as text into a xml element. `post.text =  str([1,2,3])`

Answer (score 0):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> ```
> I think you'd better like to use json to serialize your data. But you can always serialize as text into a xml element. 
>
> post.text = str([1,2,3])
> ```
>
> – Jean-François Fabre